# Does Java automatically optimize for loops for multi-core processors

Tags: java, for-loop, optimization, multiprocessing

A fellow developer told me today that Java (or the JIT) can automatically optimize the execution of a for loop so that it uses all of the available CPUs on the computer, so long as the code in each iteration of the for loop can execute without relying on variables modified in previous iterations of the loop.

Is this outrageous wishful thinking, or is there any truth in it?

Comment: So if you had a single threaded for-loop, JIT would automatically make it multithreaded?

Comment: Write a long loop that fits that description, run it, and check how many CPU cores are busy.

Comment: Check this: http://embarcaderos.net/2011/01/23/parallel-processing-and-multi-core-utilization-with-java/

Comment: Actually I read an article some year ago stating that it has been proven that that kind of information can be extracted from the code, so in the future multi-threading is a thing of the past. Not sure if we're there yet. Can't remember the article...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Java does not do this.

This can be verified by writing a simple program which does some work, and checking how many CPU cores are busy.

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; i++) {
        String s = "this XXX a test".replaceAll("XXX", " is ");
    }
}
```

When you run this, you will see that *only* one CPU core gets used. If you want to parallelize something like this, you need to use multiple threads, which can be done using the Java 8 Stream API or easily with `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. JVM would have to prove that your `for` loop body can be safely parallelised and it is a very complex problem.

If you are interested in parallelising some of your logic you might take a look at [Java 8 Stream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and its support for parallel streams.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your fellow might be referring to  Fork/Join in Java 7.
Please take a look at this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Note that, if you look at the features of Java 7/8 you will notice that most of the features main target is performance and usage of multi-core. like Fork/Join, Parallel Array Sorting (based on Fork and Join) and other features

Answer (score 1):

As of now it would seem that this is indeed done.  I was testing a program that had three perfectly ordinary nested for loops that copied one 2d array into another 2d array 10 times to average out variability. At run time, the program scaled up to use all of the cores on my machine as viewed from activity monitor. 
 I then used the time command to measure the cpu and real time of the process and got the following results:

```
$ time java ArraysTest

real    0m17.562s
user    1m9.429s
sys     0m1.775s
```

The only way I can see that it could have used more user time than real time is if it were using multiple cpu cores.  From this I have to conclude that java optimized the code by parallelizing it.